# How do I secure my WAMP so only localhost can access root directory?

Tags: apache, wampserver

I've managed to setup my WAMP configuration so I can show my clients their websites while they're in development, but I want to secure the root directory so only I can access it.

As it stands now, anyone can simply go to the domain name and see all the other projects I'm working on.

For example, I want to be able to give my clients access to: http://example.com/customer1 but I don't want them to see http://example.com.

I know I have to configure something in my `httpd.conf` file but not really sure what to do.

Hope I explained this properly.

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Deny From All
Allow From localhost 127.0.0.1
```

It's some time since I used apache, but this should do it.