# Local and Private IP Issue on Wamp Server

Tags: ip, wamp, server

I'm having some problem regarding wamp server and my IP Address. In our company we have a machine that has a LOCAL IP of 192.168.x.xxx so basically we have wamp installed on it and every PC on the local network can access the websites hosted on it. However, that machine as also a PUBLIC IP of 116.50.xxx.xxx which when accessed on the outside network you can still access the websites hosted on it (C:/wamp/www) which I think shouldn't be happening. Is there a way that whenever I tried to access the Public IP there's a password prompt or something that will block the access using the public IP? Thanks

Comment: This may be of use. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727331/wampserver-homepage-only-visible-from-localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows systems, you can restrict the access by using firewall settings using the [inbound rules](https://superuser.com/questions/48343/what-are-inbound-and-outbound-rules-for-windows-firewall).

This may help your with your rules configuration

http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/firewall/howto/windows/tsp/inbound.cfm